# while loop and php-mailer

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, phpmailer

I use phpmailer to send email when an action is done. Now this is the last part of my phpmailer code

```
$mail->Subject = 'Nuovo Ordine';
$mail->Body = $ordine_iniz.$ordine_cent.$ordine_fine;
$mail->AltBody = '';
```

and this are the variable I'd like to insert in body

```
$ordine_iniz='
Nuovo Ordine Spiaggia dal Sig./Sig.ra '.$nome.' '.$cognome.'<br />
<table style="text-align:center;" cellpadding="5">
<thead style="background-color:#EBE9E9">
<tr>
<th scope="col">#</th>
<th scope="col">Prodotto</th>
<th scope="col">Quantit&agrave;</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="background-color:F5FFFF">';


$ordine_fine='</tbody></table>';

$i=0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$ordine_cent='<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.$row["prodotto"].'</td
<td>'.$row["quantita"].'</td></tr>';
$i++;}
```

Now the problem is that mail send works but the table in the mail gives to me only a row with the last result of the table 'table'. I'd like to have all rows

How can I solve it?

Comment: where is your code inserting into your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append, you are re-assigning `$ordine_cent` on every go around. Before the while loop, initialize `$ordine_cent = ''` or something. After that do this inside the while loop:

```
$ordine_cent .= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.$row["prodotto"].'</td<td>'.$row["quantita"].'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: @cicciopasticcio No problem!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$ordine_cent=
```

do

```
$ordine_cent .=
```

as `=` wil overwrite the old value rather than append to it.